# Youtube-api, how to check if I liked or disliked current video?

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

In [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings), we have an API to add rating (like/dislike) for a specified video. But I don't see any video to check this. For example, when I load a list of video, then view video details, how to check if I have liked/disliked this video ?

Comment: This is the final answer I found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14395419/523325

Comment: Here is more useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20053703/1037294

Answer (score -1):

This is a two step process, but you only need to do the first step once.

First, fetch the ID for the user's "Likes" playlist. You can do this via the [Channels API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

Note that the data you're looking for is in the response["items"]["relatedPlaylists"]["likes"] element. Cache this ID somewhere. This ID shouldn't change, so you can hold on to it for the user in local persistent storage like a database.

Use the "Playlist items" API to fetch the items the user has "liked". The video ID should be in the contentDetails section of each playlist item. Compare this to the ID of the current video, and you should know if the user has "liked" the video or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find any element you said. Could you please give me more details?

Comment: What I see is ""gd$rating":{
"average":4.931263,
"max":5,
"min":1,
"numRaters":129595,
"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"
},
"yt$statistics":{
"favoriteCount":"0",
"viewCount":"25439208"
},
"yt$rating":{
"numDislikes":"2227",
"numLikes":"127368"
},". No element tell that I liked or disliked this video.