# Youtube-API: How to determine if I liked a video before?

Tags: youtube-api

I am developing a client of Youtube for iOS devices. I want to check if logged user did Like or dislike a specified video or not. But I can't find any support API ([here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings))

When I load the feed of videos, I just found rating information below , No thing shows that logged user liked or disliked this video.

```
{
   "gd$rating":{
      "average":4.8963733,
      "max":5,
      "min":1,
      "numRaters":193,
      "rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"
   },
   "yt$statistics":{
      "favoriteCount":"0",
      "viewCount":"111626"
   },
   "yt$rating":{
      "numDislikes":"5",
      "numLikes":"188"
   }
}
```

Did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using YouTube Data API v3.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating

Comment: This would be better if we are displaying only one video details and interactions in one scene, If there are more then 100 videos to be displayed a time we need to send 100 requests to get the like status, But really helped me a lot to get the like status of the user

Comment: @Nagaraj you can put 50 video ids in ID parameter of request and get user rating back for all videos at once.

Answer (score 2):

This is API v3, checkout this page :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists

Comment: Now I am using Youtube-api v2 because V3 is developing. can I do this on v2? Or, if I use V3 to get the like rating, and V2 for others. Is this possible?

Comment: Oh, I found this "The API supports the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol" at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings, So I think the answer is: YES.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, The official client youtube on android and iOS devices does not support this. User can't see that he/she liked or disliked a video. And, when I press "like" or "dislike" on iPad youtube app, the number of like on the youtube web does not change.

Unbelievable!

Comment: Maybe it wasn't an option when you posted this comment but you can definitely like/dislike on the official YouTube app on iOS now. [edit: oops, I think you were referring to the v3 API, not the apps]